# CLI bump version number with yarn berry

Tags: yarnpkg, versioning, package.json, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I recently upgraded yarn to yarn berry (v2) and I can't find any equivalent of `yarn version --patch`. [The documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#cli-commands) about differences related to cli commands do not mention `yarn version`.

Is there a way to bump a package version number using yarn berry cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf [`yarn version`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/version)

> Apply a new version to the current package.
>
> Immediately bump the version to the next major :
>
> ```
> yarn version major
> ```

So just replace `major` by `patch` in your case

Comment: I feel so stupid... Thanks ! I didn't saw that was a plugin to import